# Nextjs 13 custom webpack for module federation

Tags: reactjs, next.js, webpack-5, next.js13

Problem Summary
I have created a two react which exposes and consumes shared component using webpack module federation plugin. It works perfetcly fine. Now when I have a nextjs 13 project where I want to consume and expose components using custom webpack inside nextjs config file, I am getting error. I dont want to use custom libraries like @module-federation/nextjs-mf as nextjs have inbuild webpack and I want to just utilise it by customising it and using plugin **require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin")**
I would really appreciate if you share your approach or links for follow up.

App 1 webpack configuration file

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");

const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;
module.exports = (_, argv) => ({
  output: {
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".jsx", ".js", ".json"],
  },

  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        type: "javascript/auto",
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|s[ac]ss)$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "home",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      remotes: {},
      exposes: {
        "./Header": "./src/Header.jsx",
        "./Footer": "./src/Footer.jsx",
        "./products": "./src/products.js"
      },
      shared: {
        ...deps,
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
        },
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
    }),
  ],
});
```

App 2 webpack configuration file

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");

const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;
module.exports = (_, argv) => ({
  output: {
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3001/",
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".jsx", ".js", ".json"],
  },

  devServer: {
    port: 3001,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        type: "javascript/auto",
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|s[ac]ss)$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "pdp",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      remotes: {
        home: "home@http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js"
      },
      exposes: {},
      shared: {
        ...deps,
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
        },
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
    }),
  ],
});
```

Now these two react projects are working perfectly fine, but when I try to import or expose the same things in nextjs 13 using webpack module federation, I am getting error and not able to consume the shared header and footer.

nextjs project config

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
//const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack(config, options) {
    if (!options.isServer) {
      config.plugins.push(
        new options.webpack.container.ModuleFederationPlugin({
          name: 'host',
          remotes: {
            home: "home@http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js"
          },
          filename: 'static/chunks/remoteEntry.js',
        }),
      );
    }

    return config;
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```